# DNS Doctoring / Reply Modification on Cisco 1900 series ISR

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios-15, dns

We have a **Cisco 1900 ISR** and have recently setup a web-server at `ourdomain.com`. 
The site works perfectly, however from the LAN we cannot use `ourdomain.com` to access the site, instead everyone has to use the local IP address `10.1.1.xxx`.

I've come to understand that its a limitation with Cisco routers. My extensive googling has turned up **DNS doctoring** (or DNS reply modification)

I've attempted many time to setup DNS doctoring but I just cant get it work, I believe because our ISR doesnt have the capability to peform the commands I'm trying:

```
object network our_server
host 10.1.1.xx
nat (inside,outside) static 50.100.100.10 dns
```

**Is there another way to achieve DNS doctoring or otherwise access our local server using the external address?**

Our network config is as follows: `Modem > ISR > Switch > End Users`

Our ISR is running: `Cisco IOS Software, C1900 Software (C1900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.1(4)M4, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)`

Comment: What are you using for a DNS server inside the 10.1.1.X network?

Comment: All the machines are either manually pointing to Google DNS or pointing to the ISR which is pointing to Google :)

Comment: Is this ISR providing internet access for you now?  If so, please show us the interface and NAT configuration.  If not, what are you using for an internet router / firewall?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've attempted many time to setup DNS doctoring but I just cant get it work, I believe because our ISR doesnt have the capability to peform the commands I'm trying

Your first problem is that you're using Cisco ASA commands on a Cisco router; you're also assuming this is a problem with your Cisco router.

In reality, this is a DNS issue that can be solved with your Cisco router; however, it's normally solved with a [split-DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)

> Is there another way to achieve DNS doctoring or otherwise access our local server using the external address?

Yes... Cisco calls it Network address translation (or `nat`)... Let's assume you have this topology...

```
                               +------------+
                        Fa0/0  | Cisco ISR  | Fa0/1
LAN w/ Webhost-----------------|            |-------------------
                        inside |            | outside (To ISP)
                   10.1.1.0/24 +------------+ 192.0.2.1
                                              192.0.2.2 (static translation for the webhost)

interface Fa0/0
 ip address 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat inside
interface Fa0/1
 ip address 192.0.2.1 255.255.255.0
 no ip proxy-arp
 ip nat outside
!
ip nat inside source list INSIDE_ADDRS interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static 10.1.1.50 192.0.2.2
!
ip access-list extended INSIDE_ADDRS
 permit ip 10.1.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
 deny   ip any any
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.0.2.254
```

Assume your internal Webhost address is 10.1.1.50 and you're using 192.0.2.2 (a second address given by your ISP) for your public A-record..  Thus, when you resolve "ourdomain.com" from google's resolver, you get...

```
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$ dig +short @8.8.8.8 ourdomain.com
10.1.1.50
[mpenning@Bucksnort ~]$
```

Assuming Bucksnort is 10.1.1.12, if you perform `debug ip nat` on your router during a DNS query, you see...

```
Sep 23 23:12:29.132 CDT: NAT: s=10.1.1.12->192.0.2.1, d=8.8.8.8 [0]
Sep 23 23:12:29.132 CDT: NAT: DNS resource record 192.0.2.2 -> 10.1.1.50
Sep 23 23:12:29.136 CDT: NAT: s=8.8.8.8, d=192.0.2.1->10.1.1.12 [628]
Sep 23 23:12:29.140 CDT: NAT: s=10.1.1.12->192.0.2.1, d=8.8.8.8 [0]
Sep 23 23:12:29.140 CDT: NAT: DNS resource record 192.0.2.2 -> 10.1.1.50
Sep 23 23:12:29.140 CDT: NAT: s=8.8.8.8, d=192.0.2.1->10.1.1.12 [629]
Sep 23 23:12:29.144 CDT: NAT: s=10.1.1.12->192.0.2.1, d=8.8.8.8 [0]
Sep 23 23:12:29.148 CDT: NAT: DNS resource record 192.0.2.2 -> 10.1.1.50
Sep 23 23:12:29.148 CDT: NAT: s=8.8.8.8, d=192.0.2.1->10.1.1.12 [630]
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thank-you very much for your help. I was able to achieve the desired result using your answer. Much appreciated :)

Comment: @OrangeBox, you're most welcome... good luck with your endeavors.

Comment: Hi Mike,

What if that public server uses the interface public IP as the only one company has available.
How can you solve this request now?

Comment: @laf, you're asking about something I lab-tested while I was writing the answer.  It's been almost a month, so my memory is hazy but I don't think I found a good NAT answer in that scenario... Perhaps the best you can do is a split-DNS either on a linux server or on the router itself.

Comment: Ok, I was asking you because I hit this scenario many times with no NAT_solving_success. Here was the configuration to make myself clear:

ip nat inside source list INSIDE_ADDRS interface FastEthernet0/1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.1.1.50 80 interface 80

Comment: @laf, I thought I tried exactly that, but I will have to test again... thanks for the suggestion!